# Apagar registros em 2 tabelas com apenas 1 comando DELETE

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Modelo da estrutura das tabelas:

```
Tabela: Produtos
id_produto
titulo_produto
descricao_produto

Tabela: Fotos
id_foto
descricao_foto
id_produto
```

Podemos observar que as tabelas tem em comum o campo id_produto. Baseando-se nessa informação vamos montar nosso script.

O comando abaixo simplifica a forma de exclusão dos dados, ao invés de usar DELETEs separados.

```
DELETE FROM tabela1, tabela2, tabela3
USING tabela1
INNER JOIN tabela2 INNER JOIN tabela3
WHERE tabela1.id = tabela2.id
AND tabela2.id = tabela3.id
AND tabela1.id = '$id'"
```

Bom até aqui tudo ok, porém como resolver isso quando não temos o campo id_produto em comum?

Exemplo:

```
Tabela: Produtos
id
titulo_produto
descricao_produto

Tabela: Fotos
id_foto
descricao_foto
id_produto
```

Comment: Interessante, vou acompanhar... Mas qual seria a necessidade disso? Abrir uma transação e efetuar os commits também lhe atenderia ou não?

Comment: Sim, mas essa é uma dúvida que tenho apenas para fins de conhecimento

Comment: Veja "Multiple-Table Syntax" no manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, é só fazer o join como no exemplo acima:

```
DELETE Produtos, Fotos
FROM Produtos
INNER JOIN Fotos on Fotos.id_produto = Produtos.id
WHERE Produtos.id = '$id'"
```

Comment: Não entendi, seu SQL não funciona. porque usou dois `FROM`?

Comment: Pronto, corrigi. Era só remover o primeiro from.

Comment: Bom acabei de achar um problema, se não houver registro na tabela `Fotos` o produto não é deletado. Sabe como resolver isso? Tentei alterar o `INNER JOIN` para `OUTER JOIN` mas não deu certo.

Comment: Ao invés de usar o INNER JOIN use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: nesse calo ele falha se houver um registro na tabela `Fotos` e se não houver na tabela `Produtos`. Ele tem que deletar independente de uma ou outra. Tem como?

Comment: MySQL não suporta `DELETE` sem a instrução `FROM`. Neste caso você deve verificar antes se o registro existe na tabela produtos e então apagar das duas tabelas, caso não exista, apaga somente da tabela fotos.